# Cropping rectangle arround a face/coordinates

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I looking for a way to calculate a rectangle (x,y,width & height) which can be used for cropping an image around the coordinates of a selected face.

I have an image 995x1000 (https://tourspider.blob.core.windows.net/img/artists/original/947a0903-9b64-42a1-8179-108bab2a9e46.jpg) by which the center of the  face is located at 492x325. I can find this information using various services so even for multiple faces in an image I'm ableto find the most prominent - hence a single coordinate.

Now i need to make various sized cropped images from the source image (200x150, 200x200 & 750x250). Now I can't seem to solve how to best calculate a rectangle around the center coordinates while taking into account the edges of the images. The face should be as central as possible in the image.

Even after experimenting with various services (https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/computer-vision-api) the result are pretty poor as the face, mainly in the 750x250, is sometimes not even present.

I'm also experimenting with the ImageProcessor (http://imageprocessor.org/) library with which you can use anchors for resizing but can't get the desired result.

Does anybody has an idea on how best crop around predefined coordinates?

Comment: First of all stop aksing for best possible ways. Best is super unspecific...
Just think of what all your friends consider the to be the best pizza.

Comment: ok - _a way_ to accomplish this....

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. can't you calculate the rectangle coordinates if you are given center and dimensions or what?

Comment: It is the placement of the rectangle which is what i'm struggling with. I know the width and height but the placement is (x,y) is an issue as I can't Just place the face (x,y) as the center as it might not fit within the image limits. The face might be very close to a border(s) in which the coordinates of the rectangle need to be adjusted.

Comment: take a pen and paper, make sketches for every possible scenario. then derive a set of rules or formulas. its pretty straight forward. in general you have three options if image boundaries are violated. deny the operation, shrink the rectangle or move it away from the border.
maybe you provide a few own ideas to show some effort.

Comment: Thank you but this is isn't really helping. I did exactly that. I took a pen and paper and went for it but couldn't get it to work. That is why i posted the quesion not that i didn't want to do any work.....

Answer (score 1):

Using Imageprocessor I created the following solution. It is not yet perfect but goes a long way ;)

```
public static void StoreImage(byte[] image, int destinationWidth, int destinationHeight, Point anchor)
    {
        using (var inStream = new MemoryStream(image))
        using (var imageFactory = new ImageFactory())
        {
            // Load the image in the image factory
            imageFactory.Load(inStream);

            var originalSourceWidth = imageFactory.Image.Width;
            var originalSourceHeight = imageFactory.Image.Height;

            // Resizes the image until the shortest side reaches the set given dimension. 
            // This will maintain the aspect ratio of the original image.
            imageFactory.Resize(new ResizeLayer(new Size(destinationWidth, destinationHeight), ResizeMode.Min));

            var resizedSourceWidth = imageFactory.Image.Width;
            var resizedSourceHeight = imageFactory.Image.Height;

            //Adjust anchor position
            var resizedAnchorX = anchor.X/(originalSourceWidth / resizedSourceWidth);
            var resizedAnchorY = anchor.Y/(originalSourceHeight/resizedSourceHeight);

            if (anchor.X > originalSourceWidth || anchor.Y > originalSourceHeight)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Invalid anchor point. Image: {originalSourceWidth}x{originalSourceHeight}. Anchor: {anchor.X}x{anchor.Y}.");
            }

            var cropX = resizedAnchorX - destinationWidth/2;
            if (cropX < 0)
                cropX = 0;

            var cropY = resizedAnchorY - destinationHeight/2;
            if (cropY < 0)
                cropY = 0;
            if (cropY > resizedSourceHeight)
                cropY = resizedSourceHeight;

            imageFactory
                .Crop(new Rectangle(cropX, cropY, destinationWidth, destinationHeight))
               .Save($@"{Guid.NewGuid()}.jpg");
        }

    }
```